# component Html page flashed in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing, mean-stack

I have a several components including an Isotope Component.
This component is protected and should not be accessed unless the user is logged in. But if I type any route like

http://localhost:4200/register

and after that I type

http://localhost:4200/isotopes
the Isotope page should not be shown but instead it flashes the html without any data, only the template of the component and immediately redirects to login. 
I dont want anything to be shown when redirects occur. 
Here is some code for the isotope component.
I dont know what code to show because I dont know where the problem is

```
export class IsotopesComponent implements OnInit {
theisotopes: IsotopesComponent[];
selectedIsotope: IsotopesComponent;

  constructor( private isotopesService: IsotopesService,
               private authService: AuthService,
               private routetheuser: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getIsotopes();
  }
  getIsotopes() { this.isotopesService.getIsotopes()
                .then((isotopes ) => {
                   this.theisotopes = isotopes;
                   //console.log(this.theisotopes)
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                  this.routetheuser.navigate(['/login']);
                  });
  }// getIsotopes
}// class
```

Comment: You want a [canActivate guard](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate). it is used to authenticate a user before they can access the route

Comment: Do you currently have any state in your application that tells you if a user is logged in or is the only currently to make a backend call and await the response?

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: No its is all node/express angular

Comment: Benedikt, I use JWT for authentication. The problems keep showing. So lets say I login, the a token is generated and it is redirected to the another page and I CAN see the page with data. But if the token is expired or wrong I CAN NOT see the data but still I can see the page which is empty where data should go

Comment: I also use a package called express-jwt that checks for token authentication

Comment: @LLai the canActivate was the proper answer Once I started using it it is working as intended

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the flashing of the templates is (in my opinion) that the route needs a guard. Once I started using `canActivate` for that route, it checks first if the user is authenticated and can activate or use that route. If false the component is never rendered.